# Vuejs transition to happen only on slide open

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to do the move transition when the toggle button was clicked. I managed to get the transition to work for the slider but the text inside the class `div.hello` not getting animated on slide open.

```
<transition name="slide">
    <aside v-if="sidebarOpen" :class="{ 'open' : sidebarOpen }">
      <a href="#">Haha</a>
      <a href="#">Nice</a>
      <a href="#">Menu</a>
    </aside>

</transition>
<div class="hello" :class="{ 'open' : sidebarOpen }">
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
   <p>This is a red.</p>
</div>
```

But if we put the `.hello` inside the transition tag, transition occurs but on the slide open all the `p` text gets into the slider and no text getting visibled.

I also tried creating another `transition` tag for `div.hello` like `<transition name="cslide"><div class="hello">..` but it fails to work.

What I want is, all the p tags gets moved to the right on slide open and again moved to the left on slide close with css transitions.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/avinash3105/pen/rvKRKK)

Comment: There's no need to add the `open` class to the element. `<transition>` combined with `v-if` and some transition CSS classes will do all the work. Have you read the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#CSS-Transitions)? There's an example in there which does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is not getting animated because you haven't set any transition property, you just need to add this:

```
.hello {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.hello.open {
  left: 300px;
}
```

Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/deKLJX)

Comment: but unfortuanetly it fails to work on my real code. https://codepen.io/avinash3105/pen/YLjGKP here I removed the transition property from `hello` class and aside class but transition here works, its because vue's transition directive. Is there anyway to give different slide transitions values based on the tag names?

Comment: @AvinashRaj You can't do it like this, Vue's `<transition>` component is meant to be used with content that gets shown/hidden conditionally (like your aside since it has `v-if`), but it doesn't work with your paragraph content because they need to be shown always. The previous approach is more appropriate, wrap your aside only within a transition component and use CSS transition property for your `p` tags. If you can tell me what behavior you want exactly maybe I can help you more.